# Пустой recycler при переносе в kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

При попытке перевести мой адаптер java в kotlin возникли следующие заминки:

> Some code in the rest of your project may require corrections after
>   performing this conversion. Do you want to find such code and correct
>   it too?

Естественно i want!
И сразу же проявились неровности, а именно в моем списке recyclerView поля которые раньше отображались, теперь пустые.
Я думаю что проблема в

```
inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    @BindView(R.id.storyTitle)
    var storyTitle: TextView? = null
    @BindView(R.id.storyScore)
    var storyScore: TextView? = null
    @BindView(R.id.storyCreator)
    var storyCreator: TextView? = null
    @BindView(R.id.storyNumberOfComments)
    var storyNumberOfComments: TextView? = null
    @BindView(R.id.storyDate)
    var storyDate: TextView? = null

    init {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view)
    }
}
```

Но есть сомнения.
Отрывок из метода :

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: TopStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    viewHolder.storyTitle?.text = topStoriesList[i].title
```

Comment: а есть вообще увереность, что котлин работает с этой библиотекой?

Comment: @pavlofff ну как пишут JetBrains "Kotlin полностью совместим с Java. В смешанных проектах код на Kotlin может легко вызывать код на Java и наоборот. Соответственно, все существующие Java-библиотеки доступны из Kotlin." Хотя наслышан о библиотеке Kotterknife.

Comment: Очевидно, если существует библиотека kotterknife, то butterknife из Kotlin не работает.

Comment: вообще для котлин есть плагин [kotlin-android-extensions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), который позволяет так же избавится от метода findviewbyid(), в том числе и в адаптере. На мой взгляд он удобнее библилтеки butterknife (и работает)

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, попробуем применить.

Answer (score 2):

Подключите как вам уже советовали в комментариях плагин [kotlin-android-extensions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) и живите с комфортом:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val storyTitle = view.storyTitle!!
    val storyScore = view.storyScore!!
    val storyCreator = view.storyCreator!!
    val storyNumberOfComments = view.storyNumberOfComments!!
    val storyDate = view.storyDate!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо действительно библиотека шалит, а так как я не нашёл пока решения данной проблемы, решил вернуться к старому, менее элегантному в java, но не в kotlin'e методу, а именно:

```
inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var storyTitle: TextView
    var storyScore: TextView
    var storyCreator: TextView
    var storyNumberOfComments: TextView
    var storyDate: TextView

    init {
        storyTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.storyTitle) as TextView
    }
}
```

Ну и собственно в методе `onBindViewHolder` немного поменялась структура:

```
 viewHolder.storyTitle.text = topStoriesList[i].title
```

На данный момент пока такое решение, буду рад другим реализациям.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34356937 - чтоб не шалила :)

Answer (score 0):

ButterKnife в Котлин не нужен, т. к. подобную функциональность можно реализовать средствами языка. Достаточно посмотреть исходники KotterKnife, который состоит всего из [одного файла](https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/kotterknife/ButterKnife.kt).

Либо используйте [kotlin-android-extensions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), как уже подсказали @pavlofff и @xkor.